# find groups by event timestamps that are out of order

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, sql-timestamp

The table records events. Each event has multiple actions. Each action has a timestamp.

| Event_ID | Action | Action_Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Create Rocket | 23:00:00 |
| 001 | Load Rocket | 23:00:01 |
| 001 | Launch Rocket | 23:00:03 |
| 002 | Create Rocket | 10:00:05 |
| 002 | Launch Rocket | 10:00:03 |

In this example, I want to find the Event_ID 002, because its "Launch Rocket" action has a timestamp that is earlier than the timestamp of the "Create Rocket" action.

Additionally:

- I do not know the total number of actions for each event, which varies from event to event.
- I know that the first action should always be "Create Rocket." If, for any event, an action that is not "Create Rocket" has the earliest timestamp within that event, then that is an "out of order" event, and I want to find it.